# Magento 2 Custom price option for multiply with base price

Tags: magento2, price, custom-options, custom

I have one special requirement.
How to multiply my base price with custom option price?

For example:

Base price is 17 and custom option price is 3
So if user select custom option at that time calculate (17 X 3) and product price become 51

So please provide appropriate help to do this

I am a new in magento